# How to create a surface plot using unequal vectors

Tags: plotting

```
n1 = RandomReal[1, 5]
n2 = RandomReal[1, 5]
n3 = RandomReal[1, 5]
m1 = RandomReal[1, 5]
m2 = RandomReal[1, 5]
m3 = RandomReal[1, 5]
z = {0.1, 0.2, 0.3}
data1 = Transpose@{m1, n1};
ListPlot[data1]
```

I want to create a surface plot using above data.for given `z=0.1` `ListPlot[data1]`, for `z=0.2` `z=0.1` `ListPlot[data2]`....how to combine all this to get a surface plot?. I tried `ListPlot3D` but work only with matrices. how to overcome this problem. And the resulting surface plot should be like in the x-axis (`z=0.1,z=0.2,z=0.3`) and in the y-axis (`n1,n2,n3`) and in z-axis (`m1,m2,m3`).
And in my actual program, I am getting error something like `"SystemException["memory allocation failure"]"`

Comment: does this work: `{data1, data2, data3} = 
 Transpose /@ Transpose[{{m1, m2, m3}, {n1, n2, n3}}]; d3D = 
 Join @@ (Prepend @@@ # & /@ (Thread /@ 
      Thread[{ {data1, data2, data3}, z}]));
ListPlot3D[d3D]`?

Comment: yes, it worked. I got a surface plot. and how to provide log scale only to y-axis in Mathematica

Comment: vijay, posted the comment as an answer. Re scaling the y axis, you can use `ListPlot3D[d3D, ScalingFunctions -> {None, None, "Log"}]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
d3D = Join @@ Thread /@ Thread[{z, {n1, n2, n3}, {m1, m2, m3}}]; 
ListPlot3D[d3D]
```

[image]

Comment: But the log thing didn't work

Comment: @vijay, does `ScalingFunctions -> {None, None, {Log[#] &, Exp[#] &} }` work? It seems to work in version 11.2 (in wolfram cloud) when I use `m1 = RandomReal[10^4, 5];m2 = RandomReal[10^4 , 5];
m3 = RandomReal[10^4 , 5];`

Comment: No, it is also not working